# How to detect when a mail is sent in vmime

Tags: c++, email, vmime

I send mail from vmime using the following code:

```
vmime::string urlString;

urlString="smtp://outgoing.verizon.net";

vmime::utility::url url(urlString);

vmime::ref <vmime::net::transport> tr =
g_session->getTransport(url,vmime::create <interactiveAuthenticator>());

// You can also set some properties (see example7 to know the properties

// available for each service). For example, for SMTP:
tr->setProperty("options.need-authentication", true);
tr->setProperty("auth.username", userName);
tr->setProperty("auth.password", password);
fromString=userName+"@verizon.net";
vmime::mailbox from(fromString);
vmime::mailboxList to;
toString = toUserName+"@verizon.net";
to.appendMailbox(vmime::create <vmime::mailbox>(toString));
std::ostringstream data;
data<<subjectId;
// Connect to server
tr->connect();
// Send the message
vmime::string msgData = data.str();
vmime::utility::inputStreamStringAdapter vis(msgData);
tr->send(from, to, vis, msgData.length());
logMsg(DEBUG,2,"Thread Id: %ld,Sent the data in the transaction",pthread_self());
```

I see that the sent data is succesful from the log.
But when i connect to the box[to which the mail was sent] and check the inbox, i see 0 mails to that inbox.
There is no excepton or error from vmime.
when i connect to the web version of the mail box.Iam unable to see any transactions is sent box, even for the succesful mails.Can anyone help how i can see the mails sent in the sent box?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

use any sniffer to catch SMTP traffic from your host. if everything looks good (i.e. SMTP session correct), then it's not a problem of your host, but remote MTA (make sure your email wasn't detected as SPAM & etc)